# Why is the input capacitor calculation different in TI datasheet?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, buck

Below is the input capacitor calculation from [TI datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65296.pdf?ts=1630401532499&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS65296)
[image]

Why is it different from standard buck calculation given below?
[Another TI dcoument](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt670/slyt670.pdf?ts=1630393452629&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are approximately equal. On one hand you have this: -

$$\dfrac{I_{OUT}}{V_{IN(RIPPLE)}\cdot F_{SW}} \times \dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}}$$

And, on the other hand you have this: -

$$\dfrac{I_{OUT}}{V_{IN(RIPPLE)}\cdot F_{SW}} \times D(1-D)$$

For a synchronous buck converter, \$D = \dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}}\$ so, it just means that (1-D) should be a value close to unity for the two equations to be reasonably close. I note that D in the example above is between 0.086 and 0.121 hence, (1-D) is between 0.914 and 0.879 i.e. close to unity.

At the end of the day you are trying to determine a minimum value for Cin but, in reality, you'd probably double that value to ensure all bases were covered.